# Why is myAxios POST request in Vue failing and returning "getter and setter"?

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, http, axios

**Background**: I have an app where I am trying to submit data via Axios to my express Api. The express backend is successful on postman.

**Problem**: My POST request worked perfectly fine but once I created a Vuex store, the request passes but does not update on my Mongodb database.

**Additional**: When logging the response the data is shown as "getter and setter" I will show an example below:

[image: This is what it logs]

**Vue component template**

```
  <form>

          <label for="monthlypay">Monthly pay</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            v-model.number="earnings"/>
          <input
                class="form-control"
                v-model="expense.expensesKey"
                type="text"
              />
           <input
                class="form-control"
                v-model.number="expense.expensesValue"
                type="number"
              />
          <div class="submit">
            <div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                @clickt="submitBudget">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

**Vue component data object**

```
 data() {
    return {
      earnings: "",
      expenses: [
        {
          expensesKey: "",
          expensesValue: null,
          subExpense: null,
        },
      ],
}
```

**POST request**

```
    submitBudget() {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:4000/api/budget", {
          earnings: this.earnings,
          expenses: this.expenses,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);

        });
    },
```

Comment: With axios you need `response.data`, that's where the actual server reply is stored. (also, axios is obsolete now that fetch() exists, I suggest using that instead)

Answer (score 0):

The getter and setter methods are how Vue proxies these requests. To debug, please change this piece in your `submitBudget()` function:

```
.then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
```

to:

```
.then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data);
            })
```

And you should see some real data